# Run Selenium with chromedriver in Jenkins

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run a basic script using Selenium with chromedriver within Jenkins (CI).

Basically I did all the steps that should be taken to run the script but still i'm getting an errors like:

> WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

or

> 'chrome' executable needs to be in PATH.

I've installed the chrome driver plugin in Jenkins (basically i've installed any plugin that can be related) but still i'm not able to run the script.

the script is:

```
import os
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def chat():

# setting Chrome headless webdriver
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, 
executable_path=chrome_driver)


# set url's
website_url = "<some url>"

# verify the website and BO are live
web = requests.get(website_url)
if web.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception("Error in URL's")
else:
    driver.get(website_url)
    driver.find_element_by_id("some_id").click()
    driver.quit()
```

The code is just to show how i call chromedriver

What am i doing wrong? am i missing a set to run this kind of script?

Comment: Make sure your executable_path is correct or else keep the `.exe` file in same path where the file there

Comment: Chrome driver != chrome executable. Edit the environment you're running your tests in PATH variable to append the location of the chrome binary. If Jenkins runs on a system user other than your own, make sure that user has read/execute rights on the chrome location. May be worth mentioning you're running Linux, would save you from getting Windows-related answers.

Answer (score 0):

The error **`'chrome' executable needs to be in PATH`** says it all.

### Probable reasons are :

- Google Chrome was not installed at the default location.
- Actual `Chrome Browser Binary` path doesn't matches as set within `Environmental Variables`

### Solution :

- Ensure actual `Chrome Browser Binary` path matches with the settings within `Environmental Variables`
- Uninstall **`Chrome Browser`** completely through `Revo Uninstaller` and ensure `Registry Entries` related to `Chrome` are deleted.
- Install **`Chrome Browser`**.
- Execute your `Test`.